# Why use Uri.Builder and not just string and concatente parameters to it?

Tags: java, string, uri

I was just wondering why it is advised to use a `Uri.Builder` instead of just using just strings and concatenating the parameters to it?.

Can someone please explain it with some short example?

Is it because of efficiency (because Strings are immutable..etc (but then we can use `Stringbuilder` or `StringBuffer`) )

Or there are any security issues involved with Strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) is quite complicated when you look at it from a distant perspective: there's a scheme, an authority, a path, queries... Moreover, you have to remember how to properly encode your data. All this is quite crumbersome and it is a repetitive task.

[`UriBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) is designed to abstract you away from all this. It will properly encode your parameters and will properly build your `URI` without too much hassle and with a simple syntax:

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").path("{a}").queryParam("name", "{value}").build("segment", "value");
```

will build the following URI: `http://localhost/segment?name=value`. `{a}` path will be replaced by the first parameter of `build` and `{value}` will be replaced by the second parameter.

Comment: When we should use uriComponentBuider. Actually i am working on spring restAPI. but i am getting problem to understand when i choose this